# Dynamic file upload controls not working in asp.net webforms page

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have a web page where I dynamically generate lots of  elements from code behind and inject them into the page, as such:

input type="file" style="width:480px;" id="fileUploadLogo345">

I also have buttons for submitting, like this:

input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Substituir Logo" onclick="return jsSubmitLogo(345);">

(The javascript function always returns true...)

No matter what I try, I am unable to get any of the uploaded files from code behind.
I tried adding enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form, I tried adding runat="server" to the file upload controls, I have no idea what else I could try. No matter what I do, in code behind Request.Files.Count equals zero.
Any idea what I could be doing wrong?
If it makes any difference, I am using a master page...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using "id" attributes in your html... you should instead use "name" attributes, and everything will show up fine in code behind.